# Scaffold-DbContext / Method 'Create' / PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60?

Tags: entity-framework

I am using windows 10, version 10.0.19044 build 19044. I am trying to install entity framework to my .net standard 2.0. I have installed :
[image: packages installed]
I have seen in places that SQL 2.2.2 should be 3.1?
Unless I missed something the charts show that all is compatible with each other? Maybe
I am missing something?

but sqlserver works in my MVC 5.0.

But this is what happens when I try to build my models :
PM> Scaffold-DbContext “Data Source=.\MSSQLSERVER2012;Initial Catalog= MbsAnalysisData;User Id = eflogin; Password= eflogin2” Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -output ModelsEF
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.TypeLoadException: Method 'Create' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Scaffolding.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseModelFactory' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer, Version=2.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation.

I was thinking that its .netstandard 2.0 might the issue because of "no insantiation". and EF might need this?

Thanks for any advice or suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Since I am new to .net standard, I see now that this boils down to how to use EF Core WITH .net standard. Here is a great clue :
https://devopsjournal.io/blog/2020/04/23/EntityFramework-Core-NET-Standard-Migrations  .

This is the search that i used to get to this above link " using .net standard with entity framework 3.1"

About the "create" error, I had to make sure I had the same version 3.1) for ALL of the entity framework packages. But the way I was trying to use EF with .net standard was wrong I think.